# Uso desproporcional do status de moderador

Tags: suporte

Há alguns dias estou mais ativo na comunidade e percebi que alguns moderadores estão usando seu status para impor uma forma de pensamento a comunidade.

Como posso proceder nesses casos que eu perceber que algum moderador está usando seu poder de fechamento de perguntas de forma arbitrária ou tratando membros novos (como eu) de forma desrespeitosa e que estão ferindo o código de conduta?

Comment: Como os comentários viraram um longo debate, a conversa toda foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104727/discussion-on-question-by-censurado-uso-desproporcional-do-status-de-moderador), e quem quiser ler ou prosseguir pode clicar no link passado. Respostas e votos continuam funcionando normalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta postada nos comentários pelo bfavaretto:

> Se quiser debater o assunto aqui no meta, a discussão é bem-vinda, mas precisa incluir fundamentação argumentos. O mesmo vale se quiser tratar do problema por outros canais (direto com a Stack Exchange), uma acusação séria assim requer embasamento.
>
> Então, as opção são as que eu falei e são citadas no debate que linkei: trazer a discussão aqui para o meta, ou entrar em contato direto com a stack exchange (tem link de contato no rodapé do site e no próprio código de conduta)